# How to power gate device without voltage drop

Tags: power, gate-driving

I'm designing some electronics and I want to be able to control a HC-05's power without having the 0.7V transistor drop.  How could I do it? Are relays the only trick?

Thank you

John

Comment: How are you currently doing it? (Hint: add a schematic)

Comment: If you wait a 24 hours before accepting an answer others will have a chance to contribute. You are then more likely to get some alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a dedicated power switch ic [like these from TI](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/power-management/power-mux-current-limited-switch-products.page) or maybe just a logic-level mosfet. I recommend the power switch IC -- they're designed for it.

Comment: Also theoretically you should be able to get a 0.2V drop collector to emitter if I remember right